# evitar Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: laravel

Tengo 2 tablas en bd, una `works` y otra `countfecha`. Cuando editas un trabajo, y activas un select con un int (0 o 1), si el valor es positivo envias 1 y este hace que se cree un registro en `countfecha` con el `id` del trabajo y la fecha en la que se realiza el registro.

Hasta aquí el funcionamiento es bueno.

El problema es a la hora de realizar el view. Tengo un list que muestra los trabajos, pero en el momento que muestro la variable de esta fecha, me aparece el error `Trying to get property of non-object`. Este aparece solo y exclusivamente en las listas de trabajos que no tienen la fecha registrada. Si muestro una lista que solo tenga trabajos con fechas registradas, me las muestras sin problema.

os dejo el código de este view (el dato a sacar es: {{$work->countfecha->fecha_activacion}})

```
                @foreach($worksInFase->items() as $work)
                <tr class="work-class">
                    <td class="date-work-edited" data-act="{{$work->latestActivity->momento}} data-attr="{{$work->countfecha->fecha_activacion}}">

....
....
....
.....

                        @if($work->plazo_entrega != null)
                        <div class="sign-alert" data-act="{{$work->plazo_entrega}}">
                            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 20px; color: red"></i>
                        </div>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                  </tr>
            @endforeach
```

He intentado realizar un if como el que está arriba, pero me aparece el mismo error.

¿Alguien tiene idea de por qué?

Comment: Puedes decirnos que te suelta un `var_dump($work->countfecha)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con isset:

```
@isset($work->plazo_entrega)
    // está definido y no es null...
@endisset
```

o para:

el dato a sacar es:

```
{{$work->countfecha->fecha_activacion}}



<td class="date-work-edited" data-act="{{ $work->latestActivity->momento }}" data-attr="@isset($work->countfecha->fecha_activacion) {{ $work->countfecha->fecha_activacion }} @endisset">
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba! muchas gracias, no había visto nunca el isset de esta forma.